# How to structure JSON file to be used in tree graph API

Tags: javascript, json, graph

I have unstructured JSON array file which looks like this.

```
[

   { "customer": "A",

   "children": [

         { "id": "1",  "name": "B"},

     { "customer": "B", 

      "children": [ ]
    },

    { "customer": "C", 

      "children": [

      { "id": "4",
         "name": "E"

      }

    ]

  },

   { "customer": "E", 

     "children": [

        { "id": "5",
           "name": "F"

         }

       ]

     },

     { "customer": "D", 

       "children": [ ]

     }

   ]
```

and I need my output to be like this, to visualize the data in tree graph. How can i do this using Javascrippt

```
 [
  { "customer": "A", 

"children": [

   { "customer": "B"

   },

   { "customer": "C", 

     "children": [

        { "customer": "E", 

          "children": [

              { "customer": "F"

              }

           ]

        }

     ]
```

and I need my output to be like above, to visualize the data in tree graph. How can i do that using JavaScript
and I need my output to be like above, to visualize the data in tree graph. How can i do that using JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure how to display it in a graph, but you could use `document.getElementById("exampleElement").innerHTML= customer.A.children.id` or 
`document.getElementById("emampleElement").innerHTML= customer.A.children.name`.

```
`var customer = JSON.parse('{"A": {"children": {"id": "4", "name": "E"}}}')`
```

But of course you would add more to it for the other customers. I hope i helped some because I'm really not sure how to create graphs with JavaScript.

Comment: well,, I have provided sample output there, All that I need is the function that produce that output